# Editing Records with MVVM/MVVM-Light

Tags: mvvm, mvvm-light

I have created a very simple wpf app with mvvm light.

I have rows in a list view, these are templated representations of Book objects.
I can click a row, then click an edit button, this button loads a new window and sends the new window the book to edit (using mvvm-light's Messenger).

The issue I have is when I edit the record in my new window the data on the main form is updated. The text boxes are bound to the object received via the Messenger.

I know this is because I have essentially passed a reference to the same Book object around the place, therefore I update in one place.. and voilà it updates on the main page too.

What I would like to know is.. is there a standard way/method/concept to achieve what I am trying to do? i.e. create an "edit" page/screen with the option of discarding the edits?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you make your entity implement ICloneable and create a clone for editing?

Comment: Its been a while, like nearly a year. but i think that is esentially what i did.